# Reload data in UITableView from UIPopoverView

Tags: uitableview, uipopovercontroller, reloaddata

In my "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" i show a PopoverViewController. In this popover i loaded information of the row that i touched. I want modify this information and later i´ll change it in the same row of the tableView.

Someone can help me?

Thanks for all.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I am understanding you but as long as you will change the information in the data structure that acts as the UITableView dataSource you will be able to fire `[tableView reloadData]` and see the table data updated.